# Cannot find package firebase; Did you mean to import index.cjs.js?

Tags: firebase, npm

I repeatedly get the following import error at the most random occasions, when I have not changed anything in the code except for simple frontend styling. I have not touched anything, installed any new packages, or ran any other npm commands.

I apologize for the lack of context, but I am at the stage where I do not know what additional context I can give other than package.json to help solve/approach this issue.

Sometimes doing a hard reset by deleting package-lock.json and running `npm i` again seems to help solve this error; but I'm frustrated as it shows up again from time to time and I cannot figure out the cause.

(Edit) Additional context: the code works without error when pushed to production server; assuming it's a local env issue?

```
- error Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/@firebase/app/node_modules/@firebase/component/' imported from /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js
Did you mean to import @firebase/component/dist/index.cjs.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:192:9)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:768:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:830:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1035:11)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:269:12)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:153:32)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:33)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "scraft",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "check-format": "prettier --check .",
    "check-lint": "eslint . --ext ts --ext tsx --ext js",
    "check-types": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "build-stats": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run build",
    "export": "next export",
    "build-prod": "run-s clean build export",
    "clean": "rimraf .next out",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "build-types": "tsc --noEmit --pretty",
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install scraft-app/.husky"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react": "^1.10.1",
    "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-styles": "^1.4.0",
    "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.27.2",
    "@editorjs/header": "^2.7.0",
    "@editorjs/list": "^1.8.0",
    "@google-cloud/translate": "^7.2.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@next-auth/firebase-adapter": "^2.0.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^5.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.7",
    "got": "^12.0.3",
    "immutable": "^4.1.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "langchain": "^0.0.114",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "lottie-web": "^5.12.2",
    "next": "^13.4.3",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "next-seo": "^4.29.0",
    "nextjs-openai": "^7.2.0",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "openai-streams": "^5.23.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-autosave": "^0.4.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-edit-text": "^5.1.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^3.2.5",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-id-generator": "^3.0.2",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.0.3",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "react-split": "^2.0.14",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.4.1",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "selection-popover": "^0.2.0",
    "semver": "^7.5.3",
    "styled-jsx-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.1",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.0.9",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.4.7",
    "@types/draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/editorjs__header": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.4",
    "@types/react-edit-text": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.16",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.17",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```